# Finite sets defined by First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Why is a class of, say, finite groups $(G,\circ,e)$ not axiomatizable by FO logic (we use the compactness theorem to prove this statement) but a finite linear order $(A,<)$ on the other hand can be axiomatizable by FO logic. I still don't really get the idea behind that.

(Okay I merely assume that the latter would be axiomatizable because the exercise I got asked for a formula that can be satisfied by $(A,<)$. I'm guessing we could simply define the existence of a maximum and minimum element which implies finiteness of a set?)

Comment: Here is a theorem you can prove:

If a theory $T$ has arbitrarily large finite models, then it has an infinite model.

Comment: Yea I know of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem..but how does help prove that a finite linear order is axiomatizable? Oh I realized having a maximum and minimum element isn't sufficient for finiteness since an interval of real numbers isn't finite. Can a finite linear order actually be axiomatized in FO logic anyway?

Comment: What I quoted isn't quite the Lowenheim-Skolem theorems, it is just a consequence of compactness.

You are correct that having a top and bottom element is not sufficient for finiteness.

You can prove that there is precisely one linear order (upto isomorphism) of each finite cardinality, hence to axiomatize a particular finite linear order $L$ it suffices to be able to say that something is a linear order, and that there are precisely $|L|$ elements.

Comment: @James: I would like to refer to your first comment. Do you mean argument of form: *Let add to $\Delta$ formulas: $\{\phi_n = \text{there are exists at least $i$ pairwise different elements}\ |\  n\in\mathbb{N}\}$* ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Yes, that and an appeal to the compactness theorem shows the result I indicated.

Comment: Simply, then using compactness theorem we conclude that modified $\Delta$ is satisfable - so it accepts also infinite model. yeah ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would expand somewhat on my comment.

It is true that the class of all finite groups is not first order axiomatizable. However it is also true that any particular finite group $G$ is first order axiomatizable. To see this, say the order of $G$ is $n$, then we can write out a big sentence which says there exist $n$ different elements, and there are no more than $n$ elements, and then we can just describe the multiplication table for this group, this defines the group upto isomorphism.

Similarly collection of all finite linear orders is not first order axiomatizable, but any particular finite linear order is.

Comment: Okay I think I got it.. Shall just clarify it here just to make sure I'm on the right thought path. So basically the class of finite groups is not FO axiomatizable since this class can contain all groups of varying n and precisely for this reason we aren't able to express this non-concrete n in FO logic? But for a particular group/linear order we just need to define the n concretely and directly express them in the of, say, there exists x_1...x_n where x_i, x_j are paarwise different.

Comment: Pretty much: You can't say "finite" in a first-order way but you can say "size $n$".

Comment: I dont udnerstand it, @James. After all, if you can express it for **particular** $n$ you also can express it for **each** $n$. It is sufficient to get infinite set of formulas, what is ok in axiomatizaion.

Comment: @HaskellFun You are incorrect. Lets say $\varphi_n$ is a sentence which axiomatizes groups of cardinality $n$. $\{\varphi_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not axiomatize finite groups, indeed it is inconsistent as any structure satisfying it has to be a group of size $1$ and a group of size $2$ and so on. What you want is a sentence like $\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2 \lor \cdots$ but this is an infinite string of symbols and so not a sentence of FOL.

Comment: thanks, I think that set has alternative, in real it has $\wedge 's$ !

Comment: It is why I did a mistake here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124319/why-cant-we-express-in-first-logic-order-even-number-of-nodes-in-graph yeah ?